# Appending contents to a file if doesn't exist using comma separated values

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I have a file named `file.txt` with following values

```
4
5
6
7
```

I'm passing some comma separated values to the above file.

Below is my command:

```
filename="file.txt"

IFS=","
var="4,5"
for v in $var; do
    while IFS= read -r line; do
        if [[ $line == $v* ]]; then
            printline="no"  
         else
            printline="yes"
            echo "$line"
        fi
    done < "$filename"
done
```

I want the above command to append to a new file, if it doesn't exist the values in the file that I'm passing from the variables. For example, I'm passing 4,5 it exists in the file. However, it should print 6,7 as I'm not passing those values.

Currently, loops starts with number 4 and prints 5,6,7. However, when the loop starts again with number 5 it prints, 4,6,7.

The above command should produce the result as below and shouldn't loop back and print the number again.

```
6
7
```

Any ways to achieve this? Or else can you suggest me another method with sample code?

Comment: Instead of `IFS=","; var="4,5"; for v in $var; do ...` do `IFS=, read -ra vars <<< "$var"; for v in "${vars[@]}"; do ...;done`.

Comment: The original file has one number per-line? Or do you want to ignore any lines that *start* with one of your passed numbers? What is `printline` for? What happens when you run this code? If you add `set -x` to the script and run it do you see why that's happening?

Answer (score 0):

To test the following solutions I created the following file, according to your question ( *file.txt* ):

```
4
5
6
7
```

---

You can execute:

```
$ grep -v $'4\n5' file.txt
6
7
```

Though it seems like you would like to have **more control**, so
the following uses your file as an input, and the argument "4,5" is hard-coded ( you might want to change this ). It uses an [Associative Array](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Arrays#Associative_Arrays) which is available in Bash 4:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Usage: inarray "$value" "${array[@]}"
inarray() { local n=$1 h; shift; for h; do [[ $n = "$h" ]] && return; done; return 1; }
# The file which contains 4 5 6 7 separated by a new-line
source_file=$1
# Variables by you'd like to exclude.
var="4,5"
# Reading $var into an array
IFS=, read -ra vars <<< "$var"
# Reading $source_file values into an array.
mapfile -t numbers < "$1"
# An assoc array to hold the number which do not exist on $source_file
declare -A arr

for n in "${numbers[@]}"; do
    # If the number does not exist in "${vars[@}}"
    if ! inarray "$n" "${vars[@]}"; then
        # Store that info on arr.
        arr["$n"]=1
    fi
done

printf '%s\n' "${!arr[@]}"
```

Usage example ( script name is **sof** ):

```
$ ./sof file.txt
$ 6
$ 7
```

Comment: Hi Rany Albeg Wein
Thanks
Similarly we have another setup which has a file named parameters.txt which contains in comma separated value:
db.hostname,db.username,db.password,db.url,db.status

Also, we have a main file called properties.txt which contains in Line format
db.hostname
db.username
db.password

I need to pass the comma separated values in parameters.txt and check whether it is exist in properties.txt. If it is not exist it should print bottom of the properties.txt
For Example, db.url and db.status should print at the bottom page of properties.txt
Can you provide sample code?

Comment: I'll try my best. Open a new question with specific details and exact desire output for this new scenario.

Comment: Hi Rany Albeg Wein, Prior to your requestI have created a new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36722365/appending-contents-to-a-file-if-doesnt-exist-using-comma-values