# Appending contents to a file if doesn't exist using comma values

Tags: bash, shell, unix

We have a file named parameters.txt which contains in comma separated value:

```
db.hostname,db.username,db.password,db.url,db.status,codesettingsA, codesettimgsB
```

Also, we have a main file called properties.txt which contains in Line format

```
db.hostname=hostname
db.username=username
db.password=password
```

I need to pass the comma separated values in parameters.txt and check whether if it is exist in properties.txt. If it is not exist it should print bottom of the properties.txt

For Example, in the properties.txt: db.url, db.status, codesettingsA and codesettimgsB is not there. However, I’m passing from the parameters.txt. It should be appended and the result should be like this in properties.txt:

```
db.url
db.status
codesettingsA
codesettimgsB
```

Note: Already values are declared for db.hostname=hostname, db.username=username and db.password=password in properties file. I'm passing db,hostname,db.username,db.password from parameter file. So, this should ignore the values even after the comma and shouldn't print db,hostname,db.username,db.password

Is there any ways to print them at the bottom page of properties.txt?
Can you provide sample code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this awk:

```
awk 'FNR==NR{for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) a[$i]; next} $1 in a{delete a[$1]} 1;
   END{for (i in a) print i "="}' FS=' *, *' params.txt FS=' *= *' props.txt
```

**Output:**

```
db.hostname=hostname
db.username=username
db.password=password
codesettimgsB=
db.url=
codesettingsA=
db.status=
```

Comment: Hi anubhava, 
Thanks for your reply,
Currently this command is checking the entire line. In our file we have initialised the properties as below:
Db.username=username
Db.password=password
It should check only the first part. For eg: if first part db.username is there it shouldn’t print. Any sample code to achieve this?

Comment: Hi anubhava, Thanks!
It is still the same,
We have in the parameter file
Db.username, db.password, codesettingsA, codesettimgsB
We have in the properties file
Db.username=username
Db.password=password
It should produce the following output in the properties file:
codesettingsA 
codesettimgsB
It shouldn’t write db.username or password it is already there in the properties file and should ignore it

Comment: Hi anubhava,
Thanks for your reply,
I have updated the question

Comment: Hi anubhava,
It is perfectly working fine!
Thanks a lot for your help,
Is there any ways to print an equal (=) symbol along with properties. For Example, codesettingsA=, CodesettingsB= ?

Comment: Perfect! Many Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

```
IFS=',' read -ra params < parameters.txt
for param in "${params[@]}"; do
  grep "$param" properties.txt || echo "$param" >> properties.txt
done
```

Parameters are parsed and stored into a `params` array.

For each parameter, the loop checks if it's present in properties.txt and, if not, append it at the bottom of the file.

Comment: Hi Kenavoz, 
Thanks for your reply,
Currently this command is checking the entire line. In our file we have initialised the properties as below:
Db.username=username
Db.password=password
It should check only the first part. For eg: if first part db.username is there it shouldn’t print. Any sample code to achieve this?

Comment: @Rashid No matter the length of the properties, `grep` checks if param is a substring of properties.

Answer (score 0):

```
cat properties.txt <(grep -vf properties.txt <(tr ',' '\n' <parameters.txt))
```

> `tr ..` converts csv formatted records to newline separated,  `grep
>   ..` find the lines not in parameter.txt and `cat ..` appends them

Comment: Although this code may answer the question, providing
additional context regarding _why_ and/or _how_ it answers
the question would significantly improve its long-term
value.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation.